# Mock user location in MapBox Android

Tags: java, android, mapbox

In MapBox IOS SDK there is a possibility to mock user location by implementing a custom MGLLocationManager. I have implemented mine and works great.

Now I'd like to implement the same feature on Andorid, but I can not find any similar classes. Would you be to kind to suggest me the way it works on Android?

Comment: asking the simple question which has to be asked, but are you specifically looking to do this with code ? because you could just change the location on the emulator for android

Comment: Yep, with code. I'd like to show indoor location as user location calculated by our hardware, not by GPS. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The location engine that is used by the Mapbox locationComponent can be set programmatically. For that you can also use a MockLocationEngine.

Please see this article that explains how to define and initialize a locationEngine that would be used with the Mapbox locationComponent:

https://docs.mapbox.com/help/tutorials/android-location-listening/#initialize-the-locationengine

If you do not want to create a MockLocationEngine yourself, you can make use of the Android default location engine and set test locations using `setTestProviderLocation`

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager#setTestProviderLocation(java.lang.String,%20android.location.Location)